# How to access the tags/keyword properties in a Word2010 add-in

Tags: c#, properties, ms-word, add-in, document

I'm developing a Word 2010 add-in using VS2012 and C#. The purpose of this add-in is to enhance some of the document properties such as 'tags', 'keywords', 'categories' etc.

I assume that there must be a rather easy way to interact with these using the Document object model, but up to this date I've failed to find the correct properties to get/set.

I'd be very happy if somebody could point me in the right direction...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `BuiltInDocumentProperties` collection to access these properties:

```
foreach (DocumentProperty property in 
    Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties)
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("Name: {0}\tValue: {1}\tType{2}", 
        property.Name, property.Value, property.Type);
}
```

It is also possible to access a specific property by its name:

```
DocumentProperty keywords = Globals.ThisDocument.Application
    .ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Keywords"];
Trace.TraceInformation("Name: {0}\tValue: {1}\tType{2}", 
    keywords.Name, keywords.Value, keywords.Type);
```